# How to prevent a for loop from adding the same element in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop, iterator

I have a variable, representing a chessboard filled with random chess pieces. The variable consists of a list of 8 lists,each containing 8 positions filled with either " " (empty position) or a specific chess piece (e.g. "♞"):

```
chessboard = [
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','♞','♞',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','♔',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
]
```

I would like to collect the information of each individual piece in a list:

```
pieces = []
for row in chessboard:
        for piece in row:
            if piece != " ":
                pieces.append((piece, row.index(piece), chessboard.index(row)))
```

The above for loop ALMOST works. It has one problem. If there are multiple identical pieces in the same row, it adds the coordinates of the first iterated piece:

```
[('♞', 5, 2), ('♞', 5, 2), ('♔', 2, 5)]
```

The second knight should be in position 6,2. Can anybody suggest a workaround?

Comment: You need `enumerate`, not `index`. `index` is almost never the right tool.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your ♞'s are in the wrong position, where commas should be, not inside quotes. might just be an error in transcription, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` the rows and columns.

```
pieces = []
for i, row in enumerate(chessboard):
        for j, piece in enumerate(row):
            if piece != " ":
                pieces.append((piece, i, j))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension:

```
out = [(item, j, i) for i,row in enumerate(chessboard)
                    for j,item in enumerate(row) if item != ' ']
```

or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(chessboard)
i,j = np.where(a!=' ')
out = list(zip(a[i,j], j, i))
```

output:

```
[('♞', 5, 2), ('♞', 6, 2), ('♔', 2, 5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop over `enumerate(row)` and `enumerate(row)`, and if the cell isn't `' '` then add the indices to your list. This is also more efficient, as your solution loops across each row multiple times - once to get across the row, and once each time it wants to find the index of a piece.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some good answers to this question, but I find that numpy may be a good choice for this question:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> board = np.array(chessboard)
>>> board
array([[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '♞', '♞', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', '♔', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']], dtype='<U1')
>>> i, j = (board != ' ').nonzero()
>>> list(zip(board[i, j], j, i))
[('♞', 4, 2), ('♞', 5, 2), ('♔', 2, 5)]
```